# not able to scrape data because of dynamic changes in element identities

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

hey guys i was trying to scrape Zomato's restaurants those have ratings above 4 but  https://www.zomato.com/pune/order-food-online?delivery_subzone=1165 but its class name or every thing changing after next few elements

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import json

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.zomato.com/pune/order-food-online?delivery_subzone=1165')
rating=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//p[@class="sc-1hez2tp-0 sc-lhdg1m-2 hDJwRc"]'))
    )

for item in rating:
    stars=item.text
    if stars > '4.0':
        title=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p[@class='sc-1hez2tp-0 sc-izFuNb jbErXF']"))
        )

time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

please guys I'm doing it by selenium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to the page.
2. Filter out the restaurants with 4.0+ ratings using the filters provided above - using the xpath `//div[contains(text(),'Rating: 4.0+')]` (use a `click()` method).
3. All of the cards of the restaurants have the image alt of `Restaurant Card`. So you can use the css selector `img[alt='Restaurant Card']` to get all the cards appearing after filtering, and keep them in some count variable.
4. As you keep scrolling, you need to keep adding to this count variable.

Edit: Here is the whole script for you - which gives the count of restaurants as `117`

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from urllib.parse import urljoin

##### Web scrapper for infinite scrolling page #####
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"path_to-chromedriver")

driver.get("https://www.zomato.com/pune/delivery-in-budhwar-peth")

time.sleep(10)  # Allow 2 seconds for the web page to open
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Rating: 4.0+')]").click()
scroll_pause_time = 1 # You can set your own pause time. My laptop is a bit slow so I use 1 sec
screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")   # get the screen height of the web
i = 1
count=0

while True:
    # scroll one screen height each time
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, i=i))
    i += 1
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
    # update scroll height each time after scrolled, as the scroll height can change after we scrolled the page
    scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
    # Break the loop when the height we need to scroll to is larger than the total scroll height
    if (screen_height) * i > scroll_height:
        break

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
for img in soup.find_all('img',alt='Restaurant Card'):
    count+=1
print('Count of all rests is',count)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: thanks @demouser123 for the grate help code is working absolutely fine ,but I'm not in habit of using beautiful soap with selenium can you please guide me how can i fetch name of the restaurant because as i mentioned above its class and it was changing dynamically ,it will be a great help really ,please.

Comment: //a[@class='sc-jHZirH intUsQ']/div/p  this is the xpath text i want to scrape. it is working fine for now not changing dynamically how can i extract it

Comment: thanks for helping me my issue is solved now literally thanks man you saved me and the correct css selector is       a.sc-jHZirH.intUsQ>div>p